# Get user of directory (Get-ACL) in folder structure with PowerShell, is there an easier way?

Tags: powershell

this script works for finding a particular user who has any explicit permissions on a folder within a folder structure, which is good!  However, is there an easier way to list the folder path and $_.Access.IdentityReference.Value without having to loop my way in?  Or, is this actually okay?

```
$foldStruct = get-childitem "C:\temp" -recurse -Attributes D | get-acl 
ForEach ($fold in $foldStruct) {
    ForEach ($perm in $fold.Access.IdentityReference) {
        ForEach ($user in $perm.Value) {            
            If ($user -like "Dom\A*" -or $user -like "Dom\B*") {
                    Write-Host $user
                    Write-Host $fold.Path
            }  
        }                  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's debatable if this **IS** easier.

- A more PowerShell way is to have objects as output.
- instead of two `-like` I'd use the RegEx based `-match` with an alternation
- the nested ForEach could be replaced with a Where-Object and a Select-Object
- the Path would include `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::` I'd remove that with a `-split '::'`.

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\02\07\SO_54569198.ps1
$Base = "C:\temp" 
# to use a -match instead of -like anchor at begin and escape the \ => \\ 
$Users = "^Dom\\A|^Dom\\B"   

$folderACLs = Get-ChildItem $Base -Recurse -Directory | Get-Acl |
   Where-Object {$_.Access.IdentityReference.Value -match $Users } |
      Select-Object @{n='User';e={($_.Access.IdentityReference.Value|?{$_ -match $Users})}},
                    @{n='Path';e={($_.Path -split '::')[1] }}
```

The output could/would include multiple users in the column, so to seperate them:

```
ForEach($folderACL in $folderACLs){
    ForEach($User in ($folderACL.User){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            User = $User
            Path = ($_.folderACL.Path -split '::')[1] 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Understood re objects.  Mainly I wanted to get round multiple loops which you've done.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking somewhere around the same thing as [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings), using a regex `-match` to filter the users instead of doing `-like` twice.

I came up with this:

```
$users = '^Dom\\[AB].*'  # regex to find usernames beginning with 'A' or 'B'

$subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp" -Recurse -Directory
foreach ($folder in $subfolders) {
    $folder | Get-Acl | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  } | 
        Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference.Value -match $users} | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Folder'            = $folder.FullName
            'User'              = $_.IdentityReference
            # add extra info about access type for this user if you like
            # 'AccessControlType' = $_.AccessControlType
            # 'IsInherited'       = $_.IsInherited
            # 'InheritanceFlags'  = $_.InheritanceFlags
            # 'PropagationFlags'  = $_.PropagationFlags
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeh, a different take.  Thanks.